# How to get child div fill the whole available space, when parent is defined as `mx-auto` with Vue and tailwind

Tags: html, css, vue.js, tailwind-css

I apologize if this is something very simple and obvious, new to Vue/tailwind.

I have a parent template like this:

```
<template>
  <div class="mx-auto mt-4 max-w-3xl">
    <slot></slot>
  </div>
</template>
```

There are items above and below this template.
Then one of the uses of this template adds a child in the `slot`, like this:

```
<div class="inline-flex h-full w-full items-center justify-center bg-green-500 px-6 py-6">
    This is the text
</div>
```

The intention is that

- The child (green panel) would take the available free space on the screen
- But it should not create a scroll
- Ideally I don't want to change the parent template, as it's used in many places.

But instead with `h-full` I get a small frame:

[image]

I tried other options, like `h-screen` too, but they don't create the desired effect. So how can I express the height here. The desired state is:

[image]

(i.e. takes all the space available, and does not create a scroll)

Answer (score 0):

The reason that your **child** is not getting `h-full` is because your parent also does not have an `h-full` property. Considering you **can not** modify the style for the *parent template*, you can achieve this by having a container outside the parent with the full height, and adding a property to the ***outer container*** to order all its ***immediate children*** to have the **height of the parent**.

Let me break down it to **simple HTML**:

```html
<!-- Container -->
<div class="h-full overflow-auto [&>*]:h-full bg-blue-600">
  <!-- Parent can't be modified-->
  <div class="mx-auto mt-2 max-w-3xl">
  <!-- Child -->
    <div class="inline-flex h-full w-full items-center justify-center bg-green-500 px-6 py-6">
       This is the texts
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Live Implementation: https://play.tailwindcss.com/pOfeGcaeSG.

Here, `[&>*]:h-full` implies to give *full height* to all the **immediate children.**

**Fixing the scrollbar**: The reason scrollbar will occur is that when we set the **parent** height to 100% the **container's** height, this height **does not** include the `margin` of the **parent**. The only easy workaround I found is to change `mt-2` to `pt-2` in the parent (if you can).

Also, do ensure that the *container div* is taking the whole height. If not, do add `height: 100%` to HTML and body:

```css
html, body{
  height: 100%;
}
```

**P.S.** Using `h-screen` might seem like an easy solution to make an element fill the entire *viewport*, but it's not always the best approach, especially when dealing with complex nested layouts. `h-screen` restricts you to only take the height of the viewport.

Answer (score 0):

With the information I have from the code you posted it seems like setting the parent element to `h-screen` creates overflow because of the margin created by your `mt-4` class, which the 100vh of `h-screen` do not account for.
By swapping margin for padding you should be able to get the result you wanted.
I've setup this [tailwind play](https://play.tailwindcss.com/rTXw6myBic) as a working example you can refer to.

Hope this helps.